# How to get returnValue from window.open()?

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code

```
var targetWin = window.open('toto.php', arg1, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=' + status + ', menubar=no, scrollbars=' + scroll + ', resizable=' + resizable + ', copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
```

In 'toto.php' i have a javascript function : 
window.returnValue =258;

And i need to get the returnValue after the execution of "window.open".

I have tries targetWin['resultValue'] or targetWin.resultValue but not results....
What can i do ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's not how Javascript methods work [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) will either return a handle to the window or null. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The `returnValue` property only exists for the experimental [HTMLDialogElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement).

Comment: Chris, in the console.log(targetWin) i have the correct value but i don't know how to get it :
Window
​cerrar: function cerrar()
​returnValue: Array [ 258 ]